# MATLAB: How to create cell arrays with multiple values in correspondence of the same reference

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I know that my problem is quite specific but still hope to find here an answer and that it can be helpful for more people in the future.

I have different reference intervals, which indicate time periods, and different values associated to each period. For example:

```
starts = [17;249;17]; % starting points for the time periods
ends = [25;257;25]; % endingpoints for the time periods
values = [1; 2; 3]; % values to assign in correspondence of each interval
```

If you notice, the first and third period are the same (same start and end reference value, 17-25) therefore the values 1 and 3 can be associated with the same period.

Therefore I would like to obtain two arrays, one listing the timesteps for each period and one listing the associated values to each period. I am able to do it only repeating the timesteps for each period, doing:

```
time_cell = cell (length(starts),1);
values_cell = cell (length(starts),1);
values_repeated = cell (1,length(starts));
for i= 1:length(starts)
        time_cell{i,1}= (starts(i,1):1:ends(i,1))';
        values_cell{i,1}= values(i);
        values_repeated{:,i} = repmat(values_cell(i,1),length(time_cell {i,1}),1);
end
all_times_numeric = cell2mat(time_cell(:,1));
all_values = cat(1,values_repeated{:,:})
```

Which allows me to obtain:

```
  all_values = 

   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [1]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
   [3]
```

I am able to eliminate the repetitions from all_times_numeric using the function unique, but I am struggling in finding a method to merge the values that correspond to the same period in something like

```
all_values = 
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [1 3]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
    [2]
```

or

```
all_values = 
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [1] [3]
    [2] []
    [2] []
    [2] []
    [2] []
    [2] [] 
    [2] []
    [2] []
    [2] []
    [2] []
```

Is there a way of obtaining any of these arrays using the for loop implemented in the example and extending the results for any case (any start/end period, more values associated to the same periods, etc.)? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
starts = [17;249;17]; % starting points for the time periods
ends = [25;257;25]; % ending points for the time periods
values = [1; 2; 3]; % values to assign in correspondence of each interval

all_values = zeros(max(ends),max(values));
for k = 1:length(starts)
    all_values(starts(k):ends(k),values(k)) = values(k);
end
all_values = all_values(sum(all_values,2)>0,:);
all_values = arrayfun(@(r) nonzeros(all_values(r,:)).',...
    1:length(all_values),'UniformOutput',false).'
```

Up to the line before the last one, `add_values` is a matrix size `max(ends)`-by-`max(values)`, looks like this:

```
all_values =

     1     0     3
     1     0     3
     1     0     3
     .
     .
     .
     0     2     0
     0     2     0
```

so for each time step we have a row with the matching values in different column. Now we want to get all the zeros out, and keep only the non-zero numbers in each row. So we define new anonymous function:

```
@(r) nonzeros(all_values(r,:)).'
```

that get a row `r`, and return all the values different than zero in `all_values(r,:)`. The output of `nonzeros` is a column, so to keep the result as a row we add the `.'` (transpose). Now we want to apply this on all rows, so we use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
arrayfun(function_handle,1:length(all_values)).'
```

this apply the function in `function_handle`, which is the function we just defined, on all elements in `1:length(all_values)`, which are simply all row numbers in `all_values`. But, since the output of our functions varies in size, we need to toggle off the `'UniformOutput'` option, so the result for each element is stored in different cell in a cell array. The output of `arrayfun` is a row, so to get the result as a column we add the `.'` (transpose). So we get:

```
all_values = 

    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]
    .
    .
    .
    [         2]
    [         2]
```

Comment: So simple, so effective. And in fewer steps than in my example. Thanks a lot for providing this solution, it works perfectly!

I'd have a last favour to ask you: I could not grasp exactly the content of the last line of your code. Could you give me a brief description of what each part of it does?

Comment: @Giovanni.R88 with pleasure! I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not familiar with anonymous functions and arrayfun but everything is clear now! Very clever method to obtain the desired result. Thanks again, all the best!